# Regex for keyboard keys in string

Tags: python, regex, macos, python-3.x

I'm making a tiny autohotkey for OSX in Python, I've managed to send keyboard input and obtain keyboard input, but I'm stuck with one bit. I'm trying to make combinations for example:

```
1: {CTRL}1
2: {CTRL}{SHIFT}12{CTRL}
3: {CTRL}{SHIFT}b{CTRL}
```

These ones should be the ones detectable, but I'm trying to set up a regex capture group for each item in the string (Everything between curly braces and everything out of the curly braces), those thee lines should pretty much capture the following:

```
1: '{CTRL}', '1'
2: '{CTRL}', '{SHIFT}', '12', '{CTRL}'
3: '{CTRL}', '{SHIFT}', 'b'
```

I've been trying so hard on Pythex and I can't seem to make any of my regexes work properly.
[Here's my Pythex attempt which didn't work out quite so well](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5C%7B%5BA-Z%5D%2B%5C%7D)%2B(.*)(%5C%7B%5BA-Z%5D%2B%5C%7D)%2B&test_string=%7BCTRL%7D1%0A%7BCTRL%7D%7BSHIFT%7D12%7BCTRL%7D%0A%7BCTRL%7D%7BSHIFT%7Db%7BCTRL%7D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find everything not a brace, optionally surrounded by braces:

```
set(re.findall(r'(\{?[^}{]+\}?)', your_string))
```

Wrapped in `set` so multiple command keys appear only once, but you can remove that if you want.

Comment: Is there a way I can use set() only on the items that have braces?

Comment: Not in one swoop that I can think of, but you could `set(s for s in matches if s.startswith('{'))` and `[s for s in matches if not s.startswith('{')]`